# What should I post to Flight Offers Price API to confirm the flight availability?

Tags: amadeus

I am currently making a travel inspiration app using Node.js and Amadeus self-service APIs.

I am now trying to connect Flight Inspiration Search => Flight Low-fare Search => Flight Offers Price => Flight Create Orders, but I can not figure out what to post to Flight Offers Price API in order to confirm that the flight is still available.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What did you try so far? Share with us your tries so we can discuss and help you with your specific problems. Also you could have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to improve the quality of your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The flow until booking is Flight Offers Search -> Flight Offers Price -> Flight Create Orders.

Flight Low-fare Search was the v1 of the flight search that will be decommissioned for Flight Offers Search (that allows booking). A new version of Flight Inspiration Search will be published to replace the link inside from Flight Low-fare Search to Flight Offers Search.